# Graphing a polynomial output of calc.poly

Tags: r, graphing

I apologize first for bringing what I imagine to be a ridiculously simple problem here, but I have been unable to glean from the help file for package 'polynom' how to solve this problem.  For one out of several years, I have two vectors of x (d for day of year) and y (e for an index of egg production) data:

```
d=c(169,176,183,190,197,204,211,218,225,232,239,246)
e=c(0,0,0.006839425,0.027323127,0.024666883,0.005603878,0.016599262,0.002810977,0.00560387  8,0,0.002810977,0.002810977)
```

I want to, for each year, use the poly.calc function to create a polynomial function that I can use to interpolate the timing of maximum egg production.  I want then to superimpose the function on a plot of the data.  To begin, I have no problem with the poly.calc function:

```
egg1996<-poly.calc(d,e)
egg1996
3216904000 - 173356400*x + 4239900*x^2 - 62124.17*x^3 + 605.9178*x^4 - 4.13053*x^5 +  
0.02008226*x^6 - 6.963636e-05*x^7 + 1.687736e-07*x^8
```

I can then simply

```
plot(d,e)
```

But when I try to use the lines function to superimpose the function on the plot, I get confused. The help file states that the output of poly.calc is an object of class polynomial, and so I assume that "egg1996" will be the "x" in:

```
lines(x, len = 100, xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, ...)
```

But I cannot seem to, based on the example listed:

```
lines (poly.calc( 2:4), lty = 2)
```

Or based on the arguments:

1. x an object of class "polynomial".
2. len size of vector at which evaluations are to be made.
3. xlim, ylim the range of x and y values with sensible defaults

Come up with a command that successfully graphs the polynomial "egg1996" onto the raw data. 
I understand that this question is beneath you folks, but I would be very grateful for a little help.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with the `polynom` package, but the resultant data set is on a completely different scale (both X & Y axes) than the first `plot()` call. If you don't mind having it in two separate panels, this provides both plots for comparison:

```
library(polynom)

d <- c(169,176,183,190,197,204,211,218,225,232,239,246)
e <- c(0,0,0.006839425,0.027323127,0.024666883,0.005603878,
       0.016599262,0.002810977,0.005603878,0,0.002810977,0.002810977)

egg1996 <- poly.calc(d,e)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(d, e)
plot(egg1996)
```

[image]